# datatable, how to display table sorted by a column in this date format?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I would like to display the table sorted by a column called `createdAt` that has this format :

```
2015-03-09T14:46:57.678-04:00
```

Comment: not clear what you asking, if u have data in array, just sort it by date

Comment: I don't have access to the api (that was sorted by email), the default sorting for date in jquery datatables is just for simple date format, I need a way to sort by the above date format in the client side .

Comment: You could get simple date from this complicated one. And then sort.
var simpleDate = complicatedDate.substr(0, 10)+" "+complicatedDate.substr(11, 8);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above date format can be parsed by `Date.parse()`. So, if you have some columns like this :

```html
<tbody>
    <tr><td>2015-03-09T14:46:54.678-04:00</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2015-03-09T14:46:55.678-04:00</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2015-03-09T14:46:56.678-04:00</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2015-02-09T14:46:57.678-04:00</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2015-02-09T14:46:56.678-04:00</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2015-03-10T02:46:57.678-04:00</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2015-03-11T14:41:57.678-04:00</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2015-03-09T12:46:57.678-04:00</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2015-03-09T01:46:57.678-04:00</td></tr>        
</tbody>
```

you can make a simple custom sorting plugin and use it for that particular column :

```js
$.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['time-date-sort-pre'] = function(value) {      
    return Date.parse(value);
};
$.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['time-date-sort-asc'] = function(a,b) {      
    return a-b;
};
$.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['time-date-sort-desc'] = function(a,b) {
    return b-a;
};
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    columnDefs : [
        { type: 'time-date-sort', 
          targets: [0] 
        }
    ]                                     
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/kkrqzvx4/**

Comment: Thanks lot, I tried  type: 'time-date-sort-desc'  but it does not work.

Comment: The same here , how to display them to show the latest first, I think in desc way. Thanks.

Comment: @user1034127 and @akram -  add `order: [[ 0, "desc" ]]` to the options ->  http://jsfiddle.net/kkrqzvx4/2/ to set descending as default ordering for the first column.

Comment: This is not correct and doesn't require any sorting plug-ins, see http://jsfiddle.net/kkrqzvx4/13/